# document.body on change/select on change not firing, no errors -- jquery 1.3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am limited to using jquery 1.3.1 for this project, so can't update jquery.  I am trying to get one select field to disable another select field on change.

I have tried this:

```
$(document.body).on('change','#idoffirstselect',function(){
    var selected = $("#idoffirstselect").val();
    if (selected == "foo") {
      $("#selecttwo").attr('disabled','disabled');
    } else {
      $("#selecttwo").removeAttr('disabled');
    }  
 });
```

And this:

```
$( "#idoffirstselect" ).change(function(){
  var selected = $("#idoffirstselect").val();
  if (selected == "foo") {
    $("#selecttwo").attr('disabled','disabled');
  } else {
    $("#selecttwo").removeAttr('disabled');
  }  
});
```

Any suggestions?  Is there anything else I could try?  Firebug is not showing any errors.

Comment: `.on()` wasn't added to jQuery until version 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Since `on` is not available in version before `1.7`, try to use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) here:

```
$(function() {
    $('select').live('change', function(){
        var selected = $("#idoffirstselect").val();
        if (selected == "foo") {
            $("#selecttwo").attr('disabled','disabled');
        } else {
            $("#selecttwo").removeAttr('disabled');
        }  
    });
});
```